# How to close a sh session in expect

Tags: linux, bash, expect

spawn sh example1

expect " password"

send "password\r"

How to close this sh session so that password 2 is accepted in example 2 session

spawn sh example2

expect "Enter host password"

send "password 2"

Tried close didn't work 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `expect` session doesn't resume until the `sh` session exits. Just type `exit`, Control-d, or whatever you usually type to exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want:

```
send "exit\r"
expect eof
close
wait
```

Comment: tried this as well .
If I comment everything from spawn sh example 2 , sh example 1 gets successfully executed .
But i need to completely close sh example 1 somehow for sh example 2 to run.
This whole script is running under " #!/usr/bin/expect"

Comment: I forgot to `expect eof` to see that the remote session ends.